# Encrypt video and images in Android 4.1

Tags: android, privacy, encryption

My Android application saves camera videos and snapshots into the device internal memory in a separated directory (for example /mnt/sdcard/mydir).
For privacy reasons I don't want people to be able to export them out of the device.
I was thinking about using Android Cipher class to encrypt them but I suspect that encrypting 100MB MP4 videos is not a fast task, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Please read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: I've made a test with Nexus 7 Android cipher but performances are not so good. For a 10 seconds MP4 video it took 30 seconds for the AES encryption.

Comment: So CommonsWare’s answer isn’t applicable, but you won’t say why. [That’s not helpful.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/160410)

Comment: In my opinion CommonsWare answer does not give me any solution so I'm just proceeding with some tests using Android Cipher. About AES security...is that so easy to find the encryption key? If it's a password entered from the user it will not be stored into the device (or built-in into the app).

Comment: And about storing data into the app internal storage...if the device is rooted (as already said by CommonsWare) the "protection" is avoided. So probably the only valid method is encryption.

Comment: If the key is derived from a password supplied by the user, then of course the user knows the key.

Comment: Yes..so it will not be stored into the device and nobody else but the real user will know it. Simple. Unfortunately Android Cipher seems to be not hardware accelerated (in this case) so for large file is not ok.

Comment: @Duncan Jones : Why does this question has been put on hold?

Answer (score 1):

> My Android application saves camera videos and snapshots into the device internal memory in a separated directory (for example /mnt/sdcard/mydir).

That is external storage.

> For privacy reasons I don't want people to be able to export them out of the device.

Then don't put the files on external storage. Put them on internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`). That will prevent most people from accessing those files. The exception will be users of rooted devices.

> I was thinking about using Android Cipher class to encrypt them

Anyone who can root their device and copy the videos will have no major problem finding your encryption key and decrypting them.